# fips diables wireless interface

Tags: wireless, security, ubuntu-advantage, mousepad

I enable fips through https://ubuntu.com/security/certifications/docs/fips-enablement, but after rebooting, the wireless interface disappears and mousepad gets disabled. Where can I re-enable them?

'nmcli d' does not show a wireless device, just ethernet and loopback

Comment: There is no information to work with.

Comment: following the instructions here: (https://ubuntu.com/security/certifications/docs/fips-enablement):  'sudo ua enable fips-updates' and 'sudo enable fips'